# ArcMap stops displaying feature classes when zoomed to 1:846 or larger scale

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, zoom

There is a specific zoom-in point at which all of the layers in data view stop drawing and only the basemap is visible.  This includes geodatabase feature classes, shapefiles, raster images, everything but the basemap disappears.  The specific zoom-in point is 1:846.  At 1:847, everything displays properly.  At 1:846 (or larger) scale, everything disappears but the basemap.  This has been ongoing for a couple years and we've worked around it but it is a problem for us because we create detailed barn and building layouts for farms, and sometimes the farms are quite small and call for a large scale to show the detail.

It is happening to multiple users and we are all using ArcMap 10.6.1

Any ideas on how we can fix it?

Comment: Can you include the exact version you are using?

Comment: Is it happening for multiple users, or just you?

Comment: Are you using version 9.0 or earlier? If so, take a look at this page https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000007618

Comment: It is happening to multiple users and we are all using ArcMap 10.6.1.

Comment: runc "Check Geometry" on the feature class that's disappearing. check the resulting table for issues and run "repair Geometry" as needed. backup or run on a test dataset, though

Comment: I've got a server with 10.6.1. However, I can't recreate this problem. Does this still occur with the basemap turned off? Did you check the geometry (@Zipper1365's comment)? Also, have you tried changing the projection to Web Mercator and seeing if the problem persists?

Comment: jdavid05 - thank you for the tip on turning off the basemap!  Once I turned off the basemap, everything worked great no matter how far I zoomed in.  I have a georeferenced image to serve as the basemap, so I didn't need it anyway.  Just didn't realize that was the problem.